# If a uniformly continuous function maps measurable sets to measurable sets then it must map null sets to null sets

Tags: measure-theory

I'm solving an old qualifier problem which asks me to show that a continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ (and so uniformly continuous) maps measurable sets to measurable sets if and only if it maps null sets to null sets. I've proved the 'if' direction using the fact that any measurable set is the union of a null set and a $F_\sigma$ set and using preservation of compactness under continuity. How do I show the other direction? I can't seem to solve it despite my efforts. I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank you.

Of course, I'm talking of the Lebesgue measure above.